# PHP Contact form won't work

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

I've tried every php contact form tutorial but I can't get any of them to send the email properly. They all just show the code but don't send the email. This is the HTML code I have right now:

```
<form method="POST" action="scripts/contact.php">
    <input id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name*" type="text" /> <br>
    <input id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" type="text" /> <br>
    <input id="email_address" name="email" placeholder="Email address*" type="text" /> <br>
    <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message*"></textarea>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

and this is the php I have:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$to = "benmuschol@gmail.com";
$subject = "Hello World";
$message = "Name: $name \n Subject: $subject \n Email: $email \n Message: $message \n";
$headers = "From: $email" . $email;
mail($name,$email,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

I have decent knowledge of HTMl but next to none of PHP. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the PHP code is displayed instead of executed, your PHP interpreter is not installed correctly. Be sure that you have configured your web server software (Apache, perhaps?) to process .php files via the PHP interpreter. See the install documentation at php.net for details.

Comment: Okay, thank you. It's normal if it's not being executed properly on the local file on my computer?

Comment: I think you have to configure your mail variables http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php

Comment: Yes, that is to be expected unless you have installed a web server and PHP interpreter on your local computer. If you are using Windows, you can install [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) to get all the software you need.

Comment: Please note however, you then need to install ANOTHER bit of software so e-mails can be sent from localhost!

Comment: Any error message?
I don't recommend to use the mail function this way, it is easily injectable, and your site will be used for sending spams... Use phpmailer, swiftmailer, etc... instead of this...

Answer (score 0):

first you be sure that php file is exist in path scripts/contact.php

second look at phpinfo or php.ini for find is smptp server was setting or not

Answer (score 0):

use following php code:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];


$to = "benmuschol@gmail.com";
$subject = "Hello World";
$message = "Name: $name \n Subject: $subject \n Email: $email \n Message: $message \n";

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'From: '.$email. "\r\n";


if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
{
    echo "Mail Sent Successfully.";
}
else
{
    echo "Error in Mail Sent.";
}


?>
```